# Поиск значения строки во всех файлах каталога

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу понять как реализовать поиск фразы во всех файлах текущего каталога?
На текущий момент реализовал поиск в одном файле. Прошу помощи.

```
    from __future__ import print_function
    import io

    word = u'Offline'
    with io.open('1.txt', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for line in file:
            if word in line:
                print(line, end='')
```

Comment: С помощью os.walk

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import mmap
def search_file(file):
    with open(file, 'rb', 0) as f,\
    mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, ess=mmap.ACCESS_READ) as s:
        if s.find(b'TEST') != -1:
           print('true')

files = os.listdir(path=".")
for f in files:
   search_file(f)
```

либо

```
import os
def search_file(file):
    if 'TEST' in open(file).read():
        print("true")

files = os.listdir(path=".")
for f in files:
    search_file(f)
```